# I need help using the rules of implication/inference to construct a proof for the following argument:

Tags: logic, proof

I need help using the rules of implication/inference to construct a proof for the following argument:

1. A ⊃ C
2. D
3. ~C
4. ~A ● D

KEY:

- Tilde (~) forms negations (“not,” “it is not the case that”).
- Dot (●) forms conjunctions ( “and” “also”)
- Wedge (∨) forms disjunctions (“or,” “unless”).
- Horseshoe (⊃) forms conditionals (“if . . . then,” “only if,” etc.).
- Triple bar (≡) forms biconditionals (“if and only if,” etc.).

Comment: please i need help

Comment: @ClydeFrog please help me i don't even know where to start

Comment: @cookiemonster help me somebody oh god im gonna fail highschool

Comment: What is to be proven? Is all of #5 the intended conclusion? Or is the conclusion only the statement Z? Or what?

Comment: the conclusion is just Z, 5. is the last premise @MarkAndrews

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, a possible proof (using Fitch-style natural deduction system) could be:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, let's examine the premises.

```
|  1. (A ∨ B) ⊃ (C ∨ D)
|  2. C ⊃ E
|  3. C ∨ ~F
|  4. A ● ~E
|_ 5. F ∨ (D ⊃ Z)
```

The fourth premise is a conjunction.  Start by eliminating that.  Simplification is trivial but quite often useful.

```
|  6. ~E              ●e 4
|  7. A               ●e 4
```

The first premise is a conditional whose antecedent is a disjunction of A.  We can
now introduce that disjunction so we may eliminate that conjunction.  See, it has become useful already.

```
|  8. A ∨ B           ∨i 7
|  9. C ∨ D           ⊃e 8,1
```

Now you have three disjunctions, C ∨ ~F, F ∨ (D ⊃ Z), and C v D.  Some nested disjunction eliminations are indicated.  As we have to start somewhere, let us start with the latest.  This makes use of the second premise and the ~E we derived earlier.

```
|  |_ 10. C
|  |  11. E           ⊃e 10,2
|  |  12. #           ~e 11,6
|  |  13. Z           x  12
|  14. C ⊃ Z          ⊃i 10-13
|  |_ 15. D
|  |   :
|  |  26. Z           ... 
|  27. D ⊃ Z          ⊃i 15-26          
|  28. Z              ∨e 9,16,27
```

Thus do we derive Z from the derivations for C ∨ D , C ⊃ Z, and D ⊃ Z.

But wait!  We, or rather, you still need to actually derive D ⊃ Z. Well we do have two conjunctions, premises 3 and 5 that have yet to be eliminated.  So, ... do that there.

Comment: I prefer your proposed solution, @Graham Kemp. Are you thinking along these lines for the derivation of D ⊃ Z? 
[Derivation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1u7v7gognd2vgk7/screen%20shot%202020-08-06%20at%2010.41.43.png?dl=0)

Comment: If you are allowed to use Disjunctive Syllogism, yes.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.